# Gradle : Exclude certain files from packaging (jar) using annotations

Tags: java, gradle, annotations

I am looking for a solution to exclude certain files marked with a particular annotation to be packaged in jar (can be compiled but not part of jar created).

I have tried the following steps

1. Create a ClassLoader using : sourceSets.main.output + configurations.runtime
2. Check recursively within the compiled classes, use ClassLoader.loadClass to load the class and check if annotation is present (Class.isAnnotationPresent)

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to implement this long time back but forgot I had posted the question here.

The solution I used to was actually quite simple -
Using gradle `jar` task -

```
jar {
    excludes = excludedFiles(sourceSets.main.allSource.files)
    baseName = artifactName
    version = artifactVersion
}
```

And define the `excludedFiles` function to look up the files in the source directory provided -

```
def excludedFiles(Collection<File> files) {
   List<String> classes = new ArrayList<>()
   files.each { file ->
   if (file.isDirectory()) {
     excludedFiles(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()))
   }
   else {
     if (file.text.contains("@YourAnnotation") && file.text.contains("import foo.bar.YourAnnotation")) {
       classes += getClassName(file.absolutePath)
     }
   }
 }
 return classes
}
```

Hope this helps.